# Move NA to the start of each column in a matrix

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, na

I have a matrix with data such as below:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
2    3    2    8    3
7    1    0    4    NA
5    8    1    NA   NA
9    6    NA   NA   NA
4    NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I want to rearrange the data to the following outcome, basically moving the `NA` to the top of each column:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
2    NA   NA   NA   NA
7    3    NA   NA   NA
5    1    2    NA   NA
9    8    0    8    NA
4    6    1    4    3
```

As you can see, the ordering vectors for the new data is based on this ordering matrix:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    5    4    3    2
2    1    5    4    3
3    2    1    5    4 
4    3    2    1    5 
5    4    3    2    1
```

I think the best way is to apply the ordering matrix to the original matrix, so col1 ordering vector orders col1, and col2 ordering vector orders col2, and so on.

Comment: `for (col in 1:ncol(your_matrix)) your_matrix[, col] = your_matrix[order_matrix[, col], col]`.

Comment: Or do you need help generating the order matrix?

Comment: The order matrix is `apply(!is.n(your_matrix), MARGIN = 2, FUN = order)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this data

```
your_matrix = structure(c(2L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 6L, NA, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
NA, NA, 8L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", 
"col5")))

your_matrix
#      col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
# [1,]    2    3    2    8    3
# [2,]    7    1    0    4   NA
# [3,]    5    8    1   NA   NA
# [4,]    9    6   NA   NA   NA
# [5,]    4   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

We can apply an ordering function that moves `NA`s to the end:

```
apply(your_matrix, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) x[order(!is.na(x))])
#      col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
# [1,]    2   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    7    3   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]    5    1    2   NA   NA
# [4,]    9    8    0    8   NA
# [5,]    4    6    1    4    3
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I am looking for.