# Flip data in matrix along horizontal axis in R

Tags: r, matrix

this is my table now

```
    c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
r1  1    NA   NA   NA   NA
r2  1    1    NA   NA   NA
r3  1    1    1    NA   NA
r4  1    1    1    1    NA
r5  1    1    1    1    1
```

i want to shift the NA's at the bottom of each column and then shift the non NA numbers upward with out doing anything or arranging the non NA values in the matrix (suppose that the non NA values are unique), i just want them to shift up and make the NA's be at the bottom like this:

```
    c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
r1  1    1    1    1    1
r2  1    1    1    1    NA
r3  1    1    1    NA   NA
r4  1    1    NA   NA   NA
r5  1    NA   NA   NA   NA
```

is there any function that can do what i want to do with my matrix? i already found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402553/move-na-to-the-start-of-each-column-in-a-matrix) like this but the question is the oppposite of mine so i cant really use the answers in that question. any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

is there a way that this can be done by a loop? or like transferring the elements into another matrix then the new matrix has the correct position of the elements? many thanks

Comment: You can use the solution from the other thread, just add `order(!is.na(x), decreasing = TRUE)`. Or, maybe more conveniently, don't do the negation `order(is.na(x))`.

Comment: Do you always have only two values? 1 and NA?

Comment: @sindri_baldur the numbers can be unique, btw is there any way that this can be done by a loop? or like transferring the elements into another matrix then the new matrix has the correct position of the elements?

Comment: are you sure that you need a loop? The functional approaches (`map_dfc` and `sapply`) do just as good a job, as well as the `cbind`. If you want to output to another matrix use: `new_matrix <- code`

Answer (score 2):

We can try the code below by extracting out the non-`NA` entries and assigning them to new positions in a all `NA` matrix, e.g.,

```
idx <- !is.na(mat)
m <- mat + NA
m[cbind(sequence(colSums(idx)), col(mat)[idx])] <- na.omit(c(mat))
```

which gives

```
> m
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
r1  1  1  1  1  1
r2  1  1  1  1 NA
r3  1  1  1 NA NA
r4  1  1 NA NA NA
r5  1 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: is there any way that this can be done by a loop? or like transferring the elements into another matrix then the new matrix has the correct position of the elements?

Comment: @User617290653251457439 Yes, we can do it with `for` loop, but I believe it would be a good exercise if you can break down my solution and implement them again in `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

With a better example

```
df=data.frame(outer(1:5,1:5))
df[upper.tri(df)]=NA

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1 NA NA NA NA
2  2  4 NA NA NA
3  3  6  9 NA NA
4  4  8 12 16 NA
5  5 10 15 20 25

sapply(df,function(x){c(x[!is.na(x)],rep(NA,sum(is.na(x))))})

     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
[1,]  1  4  9 16 25
[2,]  2  6 12 20 NA
[3,]  3  8 15 NA NA
[4,]  4 10 NA NA NA
[5,]  5 NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

using the tidyverse, it's a little clumsy as you have to put the data into a dataframe then back into a matrix, but the `rev` function is pretty easy to understand:

```
# Reproducible data
library(tidyverse)
mat <- as.matrix(read_csv("c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
         1, NA,NA,NA,NA
         1, 1, NA,NA,NA
         1, 1, 1, NA,NA
         1, 1, 1, 1, NA
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1"))  


as.matrix(map_dfc(data.frame(mat), rev))

>     c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
>[1,]  1  1  1  1  1
>[2,]  1  1  1  1 NA
>[3,]  1  1  1 NA NA
>[4,]  1  1 NA NA NA
>[5,]  1 NA NA NA NA
```

where `map_dfc(<data>, <function>)` will apply a `<function>` to each column in the `<data>` and stick the returned columns together as a new `data.frame`, hence map_**dfc** (dataframe columns)

`<data>` here is provided by `data.frame(mat)` which is your matrix `mat` converted into a `dataframe`.

the `<function>` provided is `rev` which reverses each column.

finally the result of `map_dfc` is converted back into a matrix.